# React Native: How to import URL?

Tags: react-native

If you open up a desktop browser console, there is a `URL` object and a `URL.createObjectURL` function.

In react native it complains that it `Can't find variable: URL` when I try to use it. Is there a way to import it?

I am doing this inside `getUserMedia`, which I believe is made available by WebRTC:

```
getUserMedia({
  audio: true,
  video: {
    mandatory: {
      minWidth: 500, // Provide your own width, height and frame rate here
      minHeight: 300,
      minFrameRate: 30
    },
    facingMode: "user",
    optional: []
  }
}, (stream) => {
  pc.addStream(stream);
  this.setState({ videoURL: URL.createObjectURL(stream)});
}, this.logError);
});
```

Comment: can you be more clear on what are you trying to achieve.

Comment: sure i updated the question

Comment: looks like the `stream` object has a `toURL()` method. finished!

Comment: Cool ! I was about to say the same